# What's the minimal configuration needed to init an Autowired member in a web-app?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, servletcontextlistener, servlet-container

What's the minimal configuration needed to have the following class member to be initialized using the `@Autowired` annotations:

```
public class A {
  @Autowired
  private B b;
  // ...
}
```

When invoking A a = new A(), I'd like `b` to be initialized from a predefined bean without the need to configure it in code.

Probably some files are needed: **A.java**, **web.xml**, **spring-context.xml** (for configuring B) and **jars**(spring and a jar containing B).

**What's the minimal needed configuration and files content?**

Comment: Is Spring Boot an option? And just a heads up, you can't `new A()` and expect an autowired field inside it. The bean need to be managed and created by Spring to allow IoC.

Comment: Spring Boot is not an option. Trying to integrate to a servlet based webapp...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/), I created the [this project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1311624/SpringAutowiredExample.tar.gz). Steps to have B initiated:

1. Download and extract the compressed folder.
2. Run `mvn clean install`.
3. Copy the war (spring-autowired-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) from the target to a web server's webapps folder.
4. Run the server. (for tomcat: ./catalina.sh run)
5. Call the API and see B's hascode - `curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/spring-autowired-1.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/a/a`.
6. See `b` is initialized - not null.

The actual class:

```
@Component
@Path("/a")
public class A {

    @Autowired
    B b;

    @GET
    @Path("/a")
    public String a() {
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

* The difference between my implementation vs. mkyong's is that my pom has less dependencies and `@Autowired` member is not an interface.

Answer (score -2):

If for some reason you cant configure class A to be a bean in your application context you can have class A implement SpringBeanAutowingSupport. This works in a web environment.

The SpringBeanAutowingSupport default constructor looks up the application context from the request. It then injects the dependencies.

```
public class A extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{
  @Autowired
  private B b;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to not mix initialization technology with business logic. Inheriting from  `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` is something I'd like to evade doing.

Comment: Consider also the case where A might also inherit another business logic class.

Comment: Also, the question is about the spring+webapp configuration itself. Just inheriting  a class won't really help here. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Its a work around because you want to instantiate A yourself. This is against the Dependency Injection support in Spring. The simplest solution is to have Spring manage the bean. Just add it to the application context as other beans